# sample size in mixed effects models with crossed random effects

Tags: sample-size, multilevel-analysis, crossed-random-effects

I am trying to plan the needed sample size for my eye-tracking study. The outline is as follows:

Each participant will view approx. 100 images for 3 seconds each for which fixation data will be measured continuously. Afterwards, they will have to indicate for various images whether they have seen those before in the first set or not (memory = dichotomous variable). Because of my hypotheses, I will split the data of the time into 3 time points (second 1,2,3) and the goal is to compare the fixations between those time points in relation to the memory of the images. In other words: Do the fixations differ at different time points if someone remembers an image later or not.

The difficulty now for me is to determine the needed sample size as G-Power has not included mixed model options and on the internet there are various indications but I haven't found a program with which to determine exact sizes.

Additionally, if someone has an idea how to put my design in a specified model in R (since I am not sure whether a combination of the multilevel model and the difference tests of which the outcome is dichotomous is possible), I would be glad if you could help me out.

Thanks in advance.